# время изменения слайдера в owl carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Написал скрипт, но он работает криво. Когда слайды автоматически меняются(каждые 6 сек), то все работает отлично, то есть у нас заполняется загрузка от 0% - 100%, но когда мы нажмем на prev или next кнопку, то полоса загрузки не обнуляет предыдущее время, но и одновременно начинает считать с 0%, то есть у нас получается несколько полос в одной, как это можно исправить?
js:

```
 var owl = $('#sliderTop');

function timeCounter() {
        var numSec = 0,
            totalTime = 0,
            loader = 0;

        setInterval(counter, 60);
        function counter() {
            if (numSec > 99) {
                return false;
            } else {
                totalTime += 1;
                numSec = parseInt(totalTime);
                loader = numSec + "%";
            }
            $(".load").css("width", loader);
        };
    }

        owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function(event) {
            timeCounter();
        });

        owl.owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 6000,
            mouseDrag: false,
            loop: true,
            nav: true,
            navText : ["<i class='fa fa-angle-up'></i>","<i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i>"],
            animateOut: 'fadeOut',
            dots: true,
            responsive : {
                768 : {
                    dots: false
                }
            }
        });
    $("#sliderTop .owl-prev").after("<div class='load-time'><div class='load'></div></div>");

    owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(property) {
            timeCounter();
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно отменить предыдущий таймер, прежде, чем создавать новый:

```
clearInterval(st)
st= setInterval(counter, 60);
```

```js
var owl = $('#sliderTop');
var st;

function timeCounter() {
  var numSec = 0,
    totalTime = 0,
    loader = 0;

  clearInterval(st)
  st= setInterval(counter, 60);

  function counter() {
    if (numSec > 99) {
      return false;
    } else {
      totalTime += 1;
      numSec = parseInt(totalTime);
      loader = numSec + "%";
    }
    $(".load").css("width", loader);
  };
}

owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  timeCounter(); 
});


owl.owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 6000,
  mouseDrag: false,
  loop: true,
  nav: true,
  navText: ["<<<", ">>>>"],
  animateOut: 'fadeOut',
  dots: true,
  responsive: {
    768: {
      dots: false
    }
  }
});
$("#sliderTop .owl-prev").after("<div class='load-time'><div class='load'></div></div>");



owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(property) {
  timeCounter();
});
```

```css
.load{border-top:4px solid red}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel" id="sliderTop">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как сделать что-бы полоса шла на 50% одним цветом и на 51% переключался слайд и менялся цвет полоски?